# Advantages of dual formulation

Tags: machine-learning, svm, optimization, supervised-learning

Why do we solve the dual form of the SVM in practice to obtain a classifier instead of the primal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primal formulation of SVM can be solved by a generic QP solver, but the dual form can be solved using SMO, which runs much faster.